# Convert XML HTTP to JSON in Logstash?

Tags: json, xml, http, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a client sending HTTP post messages when certain events happen on the application. The HTTP are content-type: XML and I'm trying to log them with logstash/elasticsearch.
The problem I'm running into is not exactly knowing how to get xml bodies into elasticsearch/kibana. Or, converting it to json in logstash. I dont see any of these posts coming to kibana so I'm stuck.

When I do a tcpdump for the destination portnumber, I'm seeing packets from the client side, so they are getting to my server. This is reason to believe the client side is configured correctly.

The input block I have is as follows:

```
input {
http {
host => '127.0.0.1'
port => portnumber
}
```

from my curl tests I can send events to my index, but im stuck on why xml cant be logged. I have seen a json codec, but not an xml codec. I've seen xml filter as well? but not sure if this is the solution.

I'm still fairly new to the ELK stack so any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To ingest XML data into Elasticsearch, you will need to use a Logstash XML filter to parse the XML content into a structured format, such as JSON. Here's an example configuration for Logstash that should help you get started:

```
input {
 http {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => portnumber
  }
}

filter {
  xml {
    source => "message"
    target => "doc"
    force_array => false
    xpath => [ "xpath-syntax", "destination-field" ] // to select string values from parsed xml
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [http://localhost:9200]
    index => "myindex"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for this,

I implemented the xml filter but still no results, 
I have seperate files in the conf.d file for each part of the pipeline,

my input:
'''
input {
    beats {
                port => (beats port integer omitted)
                ssl => true
                ssl_certificate =< "${SSL_CERT}"
                ssl_key => "${SSL_KEY}"
                client_inactivity_timeout => 300
        }
        http {
                 host => "127.0.0.1"
                 port => (http port omitted)
        }
}
'''